# How can I move an object at an angle?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
public class moveball : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject player;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        player = GameObject.Find("Whyareyoulikethis");
        transform.Translate(player.transform.rotation.x, player.transform.rotation.y, 0);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
    }
}
```

I wrote this code. It's placed inside of an object (called ballers) that is instantiated by another (player) when spacebar is pressed. It is supposed to move at the same angle that player is facing (X is the only rotation value of player that changes, Y is always 90 and Z is always 0).

My logic is incredibly messed up though, what I have here is just my most successful attempt at getting this to work as intended. This shouldn't work, but I don't know what will. When the transform.Translate is placed in Update(), it will shoot itself at an offset but otherwise close to the angle of the player. While in Start, it doesn't move because I didn't give it a velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though it is kind of unclear what exactly you mean with `move an object at an angle` [`Transform.rotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html) is of type [`Quaternion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.html) which has 4 values `x,y,z,w`. So using them in

```
transform.Translate(player.transform.rotation.x, player.transform.rotation.y, 0);
```

will never return the values you are expecting.

What you want is probably [Transform.eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) which gives you a `Vector3`

---

However you say `It is supposed to move at the same angle that player is facing` so maybe it should rather be something like

```
transform.Translate(player.transform.forward);
```

using the [forward](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-forward.html) vector which points in the direction the player is facing

Comment: Problem solved with transform.forward, thank you! That's very useful knowledge to have.

Comment: @David don't forget to accept the answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: My bad, thought I did. Thanks for the notification